# Django server is slow on wsl

Tags: django, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Django server takes huge time to load/reload in wsl(Ubuntu). Running the same app on linux is fine. Is wsl it takes around 30-40 secs to load/reload. Sometimes even more.
I tried setting path /etc/wsl.conf , there was no improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likelly you have installed your django to a mounted directory like: /mnt/c/repos/django

If that is the case then it is very easy to accelerate it, just put the files under some WSL linux folder, like: ~/repos/django

Comment: This helps but it is still a lot slower than before.

Comment: @takje Moving files to the WSL Linux directory did help me. Since I'm using a Linux distribution right now, I'm unsure if there were any updates to WSL which might have affected it.

Comment: I think I missed a reboot after one update. A day and a reboot later it seems to work almost as quick as locally.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing several issues in django dev server. I switch to [Gunicorn wsgi server](https://gunicorn.org/) which is simple and lightweight. After that, all problems gone.

To do that

```
pip install gunicorn==20.0.4
```

and run server by

```
gunicorn your_app_settings_folder.wsgi:application --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Hope this works.